# Consume stream video using python

Tags: python, tcp, video-streaming, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

im trying to make a script with python that can consume a stream video from a web page. Can you share me some links or information to do this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, or ask another, to explain in more detail what you want to do. If you're not sure, you might take a look at the [Stream Capture section](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/#capture) of the [WebRTC Samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at OpenCV. It offers a lot of functions to interact with image/video. Maybe you can start searching here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/